# CORS issue with react + express

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, cors, postman

I have an express app which is serving an api.  I have deployed this to Azure.
Using postman, I can call the API (a few different endpoints) and all return the correct data.  Using a browser, I can also navigate to endpoints and see the data from the API appear on screen.

I then deployed a React app.  This then fails to connect with

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<URL API>' from origin 'URL_FRONTEND' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The two urls are different, of course.

Within my API, I have tried using cors like this:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "URL_FRONTEND",
  })
);
```

But still I try to load the site and getting the same error.  Still I can view in postman and via the browser if calling directly.

I cannot work out why this isn't working.

I am also unsure of the headers, if I call the URL with postman, I get my data, a 200 and no access control header, I get the following:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Content-Length | 57 |
| Content-Type | application/json; charset=utf-8 |
| Date | Date and time |
| ETag | W/"39-W6lvmEjJF5KqCGc8cN2eZHe9dyY" |
| Vary | Origin |
| X-Powered-By | Express |

I have also tried adding:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

to the calls in my API.

I am running out of ideas?

The front end is react and axios.

One additional (maybe irrelevant piece of information) is that on Azure logs, I can see the frontend has:

```
2023-12-07T19:31:22.591968270Z: [INFO]  You can now view <github repo name> in the browser.
2023-12-07T19:31:22.591973570Z: [INFO]
2023-12-07T19:31:22.591978170Z: [INFO]    http://localhost:8080
```

But I have searched my repo and I have no instance (other than the readme) of localhost:8080  (and that's only due to my not updating the readme.md)

Comment: I don't know Azure much, but what do you mean by being able to "see the frontend" in the "Azure logs"?  Aren't the frontend logs in your browser's JS console, not the PaaS's logs?

Comment: I fear that your use of `cors()` and then manually injecting CORS headers into the response might be clashing?  I would simply stick with using `cors()` and not even specifying a location.  See if you can get that to work, then add additional constraints once you have it working.

Comment: I had that initially and then added the manual ones in later to see if that worked

Comment: @GregFenton - even with the removal of the manual headers it is still the same

Comment: See my first question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict in the configuration of cors,

You are using both a custom middleware and the cors middleware. It's generally not necessary to use both.

In your custom middleware, you are setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to "*", which means any origin is allowed. However, you also have the cors middleware configured with a specific origin. You may want to choose one approach or the other.

I will suggest trying setting up only the cors middleware configuration like this :

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "URL_FRONTEND", // Replace with your actual frontend URL
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  })
);

// Your routes and other middleware go here

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```